# Solving a non-linear System of Equations in SciLab

Tags: scilab

I am trying to solve the following system of equations in SciLab:

```
  x^2 + y^2 = 0
  x^4 + y^4 - 10 = 0
```

I defined the following function in SciLab:

```
function y=f3(x,y)
    y = [x^2+y^2,x^4+y^4-10]
endfunction
```

That appeared to work. I found that `f3(1,1)` is:    `2.  -8.`
So I then ran the following:

```
fsolve([0,0], f3)
```

and I got:

```
fsolve: exception caught in 'fct' subroutine.
at line     2 of function f3
in builtin                fsolve

Undefined variable: y
```

I then defined the function `fct` as follows:

```
function y=fct(x,y)
    y = [2*x+2*y, 4*x^3+4*y^3]
endfunction
```

I then ran the command:

```
fsolve([0,0], f3, fct)
```

and that produced the following message:

```
fsolve: exception caught in 'jac' subroutine.
at line     2 of function f3
in builtin                fsolve

Undefined variable: y
```

Any additional comments? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking [`help fsolve`](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.1/en_US/fsolve.html), you'll see that `fsolve` works on functions of single argument. That means your `f3` should receive a vector `v` instead of `x`and `y`, having that `x = v(1)` and `y = v(2)`. So your function should be:

```
function y = f3(v)
    y = [v(1)^2 + v(2)^2,...
         v(1)^4 + v(2)^4-10]
endfunction
```

This will solve the problem of not being able to run `fsolve`. **However**, a more serious problem is that your system have no single solution, because any point (x,y) that lies in the curve `x^2 + y^2 = x^4 + y^4 - 10` is a solution to your system. Therefore, `fsolve` will not be able to find any solution at all:

```
--> [y,val,info]=fsolve([0,0],f3)
 info  = 
   4.
 val  = 
   0.  -10.
 y  = 
   0.   0.
```

The help page says that for `info == 4`, "iteration is not making good progress."